# Send/Receive in Outlook via code

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

If I create an Outlook 2010 object In Excel VBA using

```
Sub CreateOL()
    On Error Resume Next
        Set myOlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Is it possible to force `myOLAPP` to send/receive. Please can somebody advise how it's done?

I've tried the following but it's not working for me.

```
 Set nsp = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set sycs = nsp.SyncObjects
 For i = 1 To sycs.Count
    Set syc = sycs.Item(i)

    syc.Start

 Next
```

Also, how do I make myOlApp visible? `myOlApp.Visible = True` and `myOlApp.Application.Visible = True` doesn't work

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which Outlook version are you using? I tested this with Outlook 2010 and it works.

**NOTE**: I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of that.

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim oLook As Object
    Dim nsp As Object, objSyncs As Object, objSync As Object
    Dim i As Long

    Set oLook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

    Set nsp = oLook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objSyncs = nsp.SyncObjects

    For i = 1 To objSyncs.Count
        Set objSync = objSyncs.Item(i)
        objSync.Start
    Next
End Sub
```

MS Outlook has 2 types of windows

1. Explorer for Folders and
2. Inspector for individual items.

If you want to show a particular folder, you can start the Explorer for it then either use `.Activate` or `.Display.` An alternative would be to use `MAPIFolder.Display` method as well.

Comment: Thanks - it's working now. Very strange - must be special variable names! :)

Comment: @user3357963  Did you ever figure out why it wasn't working before?  I'm using Siddharth's code from Excel VBA and the messages in my Outbox are not sending.

Comment: Interestingly.  When I use the "Send/receive Groups" -> "All Accounts group" that doesn't send the e-mails either.