# How to Send All Emails From Outlook Outbox in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook

I'm using Excel VBA to stage emails in Outlook and it is working well.

```
Dim template As Outlook.MailItem, tomerge As Outlook.MailItem
' Create E-mail
tomerge.Close olSave
```

The e-mails can then be manually moved to the Drafts folder and [sent using this Sub](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/batch-send-multiple-draft-emails-outlook-vba/).

```
'Loop through items in Drafts folder
objDrafts.Item(i).Send
```

However, many users have a bunch of extra drafts in their Drafts folder that they don't want sent.

If I replace "olFolderDrafts" with "olFolderOutbox" and try to send from their Outbox.  The first message sends and then I get a "Run-time error" "Outlook has already begun transmitting this message".

Is there some way to send all from the Outbox *or* even better is there someway to stage and send from a newly created folder?

Comment: If all mail items are in outbox already - simply simulate outlook's send/receive all mail feature - example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12303092/6187845)

Comment: Interesting, this Sub doesn't seem to work for me.  I have three unsent messages in my Outbox.  I copied/pasted over this "Sample" Sub and when I run it in Excel VBA it doesn't do anything.  Oddly when I inspect the first "objSync" VBA says "objSync="All Accounts".

Comment: Interestingly. When I use the "Send/receive Groups" -> "All Accounts group" that doesn't send the e-mails either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was inspired by Nagarajan's comment above, but there are quite a few changes necessary from the answer in [Send/Receive in Outlook Via Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12302244/send-receive-in-outlook-via-code?noredirect=1&lq=1).   The main problem is using `olSave` doesn't put the messages in a "ready to send" state in Outlook so starting a sync using `syc.Start` from the answer above does nothing.

Instead, we found the following process to be straight forward:

1. Put Outlook in offline mode using "Send/Recieve" -> "Work Offline"
2. Use Excel VBA to stage the e-mails and instead of saving just `.Send` each email.  As Outlook is offline they will be staged and ready to be sent but not actually sent.
3. The e-mails should now be staged in Outlook's Outbox folder and can be reviewed just be sure to press the "send" button after reviewing/editing messages otherwise the e-mail you modified will be removed from the queue.
4. When the messages are ready to be sent put Outlook back in online mode and they will be sent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a folder for your unsent items and process them separately. As a rule the `Outbox` folder contains already submitted items. So, that's not a right place for your items.

The Outlook Object Model provides the [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862204.aspx) function of the `Folders` class. You can get an instance of the `Folders` class using the `Folders` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook. You can read more about that in the [How To: Create a new folder in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/01/how-to-create-a-new-folder/) article.

Comment: Interesting.  So how can save to that folder?  Outlook seems to default to the outbox when I save (olSave).  olSave doesn't seem to have any parameters.

Comment: The default folder is Drafts. Most probably you used the following code for creating items in that case: `outbox.Items.Add` . You need to get the `Items` collection from the folder where you want to save items.